# Rails 3: Mongoid validates_inclusion_of error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongoid, activemodel

```
class Request
include Mongoid::Document 
field :code, type: String      
validates :code, :presence => true, 
                 :inclusion => { :in => proc { Listing.all_codes } }
```

Using Mongoid, I am trying to validate the :code input on the submission form to make sure they are using a proper code that is already in the database. The listing model :code field is also named :code.

This is the error:

```
undefined method `all_codes' for Listing:Class
```

Any suggestions? What is the reference equivalent in Mongoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a ruby level error saying that you do not have a method looking like

```
class Listing
    def self.all_codes
       # stuff
    end
end
```

The `self.` part is important.

You might have it implemented like

```
class Listing
   named_scope :all_codes, :select => #...
end
```

You might just want `Listing.all` Really the bug is a disagreement in method name between your Request class and your Listing class.